# Generating a bitvector in scheme

Tags: vector, scheme, racket, spell-checking, hash-function

I am trying to implement a spellchecker that takes a hash function and a dictionary, and then map the hash values of the words to a bitvector. More specifically, I am trying to write a function called gen-checker that takes as input a list of hash functions and a dictionary of words and returns a spellchecker. The spellchecker must generate a bitvector representation for the input of the dictionary, which contains #t or #f indicating the correct or incorrect spelling of the word.

I have already defined the has functions and have a dictionary to use, but I can't seem to get the bit vector setup

I have tried implementing (make-bitvector 8 #f) found here:

http://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Bit-Vectors.html

But for some reason drracket does not recognize it. What am I doing wrong? How to implement the bitvector representation?

Comment: http://docs.racket-lang.org/data/bit-vector.html  You need to tell the compiler you are using the package with the (require data/bit-vector)

Comment: OK so I figured it out. you have to use make-bit-vector instead of make-bitvector. I should be fine for now

Answer (score 2):

It may seem like this answer is joking, but it is not:

```
(define make-bitvector make-vector)
(define bitvector-ref  vector-ref)
;; ...
```

After everything is working, and only then, would one need to optimize storage by bit packing.